# Why is the Dropdownlist in my MVC3 application disabled when I have set the SelectedItem?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 application that I have a view defined to have the possibility of passing values and setting the SelectedItem value.

```
List<SelectListItem> items = new SelectList(db.BILLING_COUNTRY, "ISO_Code_BillingCountry", "CountryName", Country).AsParallel().ToList();
        items.Insert(0, (new SelectListItem { Text = "Select Your Country", Value = "0" }));
        ViewBag.Countries = items;
```

I am setting the disabled = "disabled" attribute on the dropdownlist if a ViewBag.EnableDropDowns is false or not set.

```
@{ object displayMode = (ViewBag.EnableDropDowns) ? null : new { disabled = "disabled"     };
           @Html.DropDownList("Countries", null, new { disabled = displayMode, onchange     = "LoadItems()" } )
        }
```

I set the ViewBag.EnableDropDowns to true, it correctly sets all the values in the drop down list but they are disabled instead of enabled.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with the dictionary declaration. It has to be`Dictionary<string, object>()` otherwise you will face run time issues.

I have to disable the listbox based upon a condition.

```
@{
var sourceListOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
sourceListOptions.Add("style", "Height: 250px; width: 225px;");
if (Model.SourceColumns.Count() == Model.ImportMappings.Count())
{
    sourceListOptions.Add("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

}

```
@Html.ListBox("SourceColumns", Model.SourceColumns, sourceListOptions)
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownList("SourceColumns", Model.SourceColumns, sourceListOptions)
```

Comment: this didn't work either.  I might have failed to mention I have 2 dropdownlist objects I need this dynamic variable for disabled disabled.  The way I had it before works but it's disabled.  The ways I've been told to try it it's always enabled.

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("Countries", null, new { disabled = displayMode, onchange     = "LoadItems()" } ) May I know why you are passing data source of items as null? Now this is a challenge I will get it resolved.

Comment: I'm setting the SelectList in code... it's complicated the name "Countries" corresponds to the ViewBag name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set `enabled="enabled"`

Try:

```
    @{
        bool displayMode = (ViewBag.EnableDropDowns) ? "enabled": "disabled";                     
     };

   @if(displayMode)
   {
     Html.DropDownList("Countries", null, 
      new { enabled= displayMode, onchange="LoadItems()" } );
   }
   else
   {
      Html.DropDownList("Countries", null, 
      new { disabled= displayMode, onchange="LoadItems()" } );
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `select` element will be disabled if the `disabled` attribute is present at all (regardless of its value).  So you'll need something like this (specifying `htmlAttributes` as a Dictionary rather than an anonymous object, as it seems more convenient in this case):

```
@{ 
    var displayMode = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    displayMode.Add("onchange", "LoadItems()");
    if (ViewBag.EnableDropDowns) displayMode.Add("disabled", "disabled");
}

@Html.DropDownList("Countries", null, displayMode)
```

Comment: this makes things always enabled... I will need to try the one below and see if it resolves it later today.